# Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm-install

I'm trying to start my project but I ran into this error:
Module parse failed: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
 replaceTraps((oldTraps) => ({
 ...oldTraps,
 get: (target, prop, receiver) => getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.get(target, prop, receiver),
 has: (target, prop) => !!getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.has(target, prop),

 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js 5:0-29
 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/esm/index.esm.js
```

@ ./src/main.js

Here is my package.json file:

```
    {
      "name": "my-project",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A Vue.js project",
      "author": "sieus",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
        "start": "npm run dev",
        "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
        "test": "npm run unit",
        "build": "node build/build.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "element-ui": "^2.13.1",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "firebase": "^9.6.11",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "jszip": "^2.6.1",
        "jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "qs": "^6.9.4",
        "sass": "^1.63.6",
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
        "vue": "^2.5.2",
        "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vuex": "^3.4.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
        "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
        "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
        "chalk": "^2.0.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
        "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "jest": "^22.0.4",
        "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
        "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "ora": "^1.2.0",
        "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
        "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
        "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
        "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
        "semver": "^5.3.0",
        "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
        "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
        "vue-loader": "^13.7.3",
        "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
        "webpack": "^3.6.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
        "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 6.0.0",
        "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
      },
      "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 8"
      ]
    }
```

My webpack.dev.conf.js

```
    'use strict'
    const utils = require('./utils')
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    const config = require('../config')
    const merge = require('webpack-merge')
    const path = require('path')
    const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
    const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')
    const portfinder = require('portfinder')

    const HOST = process.env.HOST
    const PORT = process.env.PORT && Number(process.env.PORT)

    const devWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
      module: {
        rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap, usePostCSS: true })
      },
      // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
      devtool: config.dev.devtool,

      // these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
      devServer: {
        clientLogLevel: 'warning',
        historyApiFallback: {
          rewrites: [
            { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
          ],
        },
        hot: true,
        contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
        compress: true,
        host: HOST || config.dev.host,
        port: PORT || config.dev.port,
        open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
        overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
          ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
          : false,
        publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
        proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
        quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
        watchOptions: {
          poll: config.dev.poll,
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': require('../config/dev.env')
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(), // HMR shows correct file names in console on update.
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          filename: 'index.html',
          template: 'index.html',
          inject: true
        }),
        // copy custom static assets
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          {
            from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
            to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
            ignore: ['.*']
          }
        ])
      ]
    })

    module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      portfinder.basePort = process.env.PORT || config.dev.port
      portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } else {
          // publish the new Port, necessary for e2e tests
          process.env.PORT = port
          // add port to devServer config
          devWebpackConfig.devServer.port = port

          // Add FriendlyErrorsPlugin
          devWebpackConfig.plugins.push(new FriendlyErrorsPlugin({
            compilationSuccessInfo: {
              messages: [`Your application is running here: http://${devWebpackConfig.devServer.host}:${port}`],
            },
            onErrors: config.dev.notifyOnErrors
            ? utils.createNotifierCallback()
            : undefined
          }))

          resolve(devWebpackConfig)
        }
      })
    })
```

When I access to ./node_modules/idb/build/index.js I noticed the ...oldTraps spread operator and when I comment the code everything works normal but I need to start project without updating any codes inside the node_modules.

I tried to upgrade the lastest version of every dependencies in the project or downgrade them but nothing works.